# Excel - Using CountIFS with an array to EXCLUDE results

Tags: arrays, excel, countif

I know how to use multiple OR criteria in a CountIFS statement with an array e.g.

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table1[Week],"1",Table1[Day],{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"}))`

However; how can I turn that around and look for results which EXCLUDE multiple criteria in the array e.g. something like:

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table1[Week],"1",Table1[Day],{"<>Monday","<>Tuesday","<>Wednesday"}))`

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's what's left when you subtract out the three days which are excluded:

```
=COUNTIF(Table1[Week],"1")-SUM(COUNTIFS(Table1[Week],"1",Table1[Day],{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"}))
```

[image]

Comment: of course! d'uh it's funny how a fresh pair of eyes looks at something and sees it from a totally different angle haha - I've been banging my head against the wall with this for ages. Many thanks!!

Comment: No problem! I was going to add that of course you can always put =COUNTIFS(Table1[Week],"1",Table1[Day],"<>Monday",Table1[Day],"<>Tuesday",Table1[Day],"<>Wednesday") but that gets away from the array idea.